# Netbeans - how to include characters like '$' in page search

Tags: netbeans

Netbeans has a page search feature: when you are working on a code page, you can go CTL+F and you get a small popup text box on the lower right of the code page to enter search items.

In php, I often want to search for variables starting with $, such as $name, $email, etc.  However, the search box finds nothing even though the page is littered with them.

Is there a way to get Netbeans page search to recognize the $ sign?